# No rule to make target 'D:/Dev/Libraries/SFML-2.5.1-build/lib/libsfml-graphics.a'

Tags: makefile, cmake, sfml, mingw-w64

I am trying to create a project template for future SFML projects, featuring CMake.

My SFML folder that I downloaded is located at `D:/Dev/Libraries/SFML-2.5.1/`

I already built SFML with CMake with [this](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/compile-with-cmake.php) tutorial.

My `sfml-project` folder structure is as below:

```
root
+- build
+- src
|  +- main.cpp
+- CMakeLists.txt
```

The contents of `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21.1)

set(PROJECT_NAME sfml-project)
set(EXECUTABLE_NAME main)
set(SFML_DIR D:/Dev/Libraries/SFML-2.5.1/build)

project(${PROJECT_NAME} LANGUAGES CXX)

find_package(SFML 2.5.1 COMPONENTS graphics system window)

file(GLOB SOURCES src/*.cpp)

add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} sfml-system sfml-window sfml-graphics)
```

When I do `cmake ..` in the `build` subdirectory it runs smoothly:

```
$ cmake ..
-- Found SFML 2.5.1 in D:/Dev/Libraries/SFML-2.5.1/build
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/Dev/Project Templates/sfml-project/build
```

However, when I use `mingw32-make` afterwards it says:

```
mingw32-make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'D:/Dev/Libraries/SFML-2.5.1-build/lib/libsfml-graphics.a', needed by 'main.exe'.  Stop.
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:90: all] Error 2
```

What is the issue here? Is it the `CMakeLists.txt` file that messed up? Or does it have something to do with how I downloaded and built SFML?

I have tried to copy all the `.dll` and `.a` files from the original `SFML-2.5.1/build/lib` folder, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Instead of running `mingw32-make` in the building SFML with CMake tutorial, I had to do `mingw32-make install`.